# Applying a patch that contains changes that are already applied

Tags: git, diff, patch

I would like to ask for assistance regarding applying patches with git.

Let's say I have the following git history (git log)

```
base_commit --> commit_1 --> commit_2
```

And I receive a (git) patch from another developer. This patch contains the changes he made starting from `base_commit`.

I examined the patch and also made the following:

```
git diff base_commit commit_2
```

and I noticed that the changes of the patch are *almost all* included in the diff (meaning the changes are already in `commit_2`.

If that was it, I would just not apply the patch. But the thing is, the patch contains one change *that is not included yet* in `commit_2`

What is the best way to proceed from here?

Do I apply the patch normally on top of `commit_2`?

or should I manually apply the changes of the patch that are not in `commit_2`?

Comment: The change is in the same file?

Comment: The change recorded only in the patch is in only one file but I think the question could cover also what happens when these changes are in several files

Answer (score 0):

If you like merges, and wanna have a record of the whole thing, you can go like this

```
git checkout base_commit
git checkout -b temp-branch
# now apply the patch however you would apply it
# and commit
git checkout main-branch
git merge temp-branch
```

then you will see in your history exactly what the other developer did, and what his base was, and how you combined them, so if you make a mistake, you have a record of it